# Magento A-Z page

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Does Magento have a default A-Z index search page for all the products, or do I have to do some custom programming?

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? Are you looking for something similar to this: http://www.kidsongs.com/downloads/songs

Or do you simply want a product search page?

Comment: Yeah something similar to that... Just so it lists all products in alphabetical order - exactly like that!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this one, by writing custom code - looing round the products and displaying the results... As I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any direct way of doing this, but here is what I would suggest:

1. Create a new category called "All Products" or "Alphabetical Listing" or whatever you would like to name it. Assign all of the products in the system to that category.
2. Click on the "Display Settings" tab for that category. Set the "Default Product Listing Sort by" to "Name". That will make the category list out its products in alphabetical order.

Comment: Just a note.. you can sort by "name" on the catalog product page. How would adding every product into a specified category, and then specifying the categorys default sort be any different? In fact.. I believe it would require more work.

Comment: When you load up the category - it will automatically sort by name. He can remove the rest of the sorting options be deselected the "Available Sort By" in the "Display Settings" as well. And he creates a specific category because he would need to have one category in it with every product...

Comment: Hmmm, yeah see where you going with this - I think I'm going to have to do something custom, becuase the client wants it split out with headings i.e A, B, C then list the product underneath each section, if that makes sense....